# Calling java.util.Collections.shuffle() from multiple threads?

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm doing a school assignment where we're supposed to "translate" a C++ program to Java and compare the performance. The program uses different execution methods (newSingleThreadExecutor and newFixedThreadPool) to run some work sequentially and with different sized thread pools. The work is local to each thread - creating an ArrayList of random numbers, writing some random numbers to temporary files, and shuffling the ArrayList.

I've run into a problem where the sequential execution is faster than the concurrent execution, and I seem to have pinpointed it down to using `java.util.Collections.shuffle(myArrayListOfIntegers)`. This seems to use a static instance of `java.util.Random` to shuffle the list, and that seems to be what's causing my problems - if I make my own shuffle method, exactly like the above mentioned one but using a new instance of Random for every call, things improve greatly.

**Question 1.** Am I correct in assuming that the static Random instance is what's causing my problems?

The `java.util.Collections.shuffle(List<?> list)` method looks like this

```
public static void shuffle(List<?> list) {
    Random rnd = r;
    if (rnd == null)
        r = rnd = new Random(); // harmless race.
    shuffle(list, rnd);
}

private static Random r;
```

**Question 2.** What is the `Random rnd = r;` in the above method supposed to do? Doesn't it just copy the reference? Why not use `Random rnd = new Random()`instead (which seems to solve my problems)?

Comment: "sequential execution is faster than the concurrent execution". This could be correct because it does not have thread waiting overhead. I dont see any problem with random. Can you provide a little more code? And did you check the other shuffle method with two parameter? It has some other things involved.

Comment: Question 3: why are you attempting to shuffle the same collection from two different threads?

Answer (score 1):

> Question 1. Am I correct in assuming that the static Random instance is what's causing my problems?

Probably not.  The shuffle is going to be `O(N)` or something so I doubt it is the source of your problems.  It does use volatile variables internally to make it threadsafe which might be a problem, especially if there is a ton of thread contention, but IO is usually a lot more expensive.  You could try using a local copy of [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) which doesn't use `volatile` fields to compare it's performance.

```
Collections.shuffle(list, ThreadLocalRandom.current());
```

To figure that out is going to take a profiler or some other analysis of your program.  Watch for any IO (input, output, logging, etc.).  Java programs are notoriously hard to infer performance information from wall clock calculations since there is so much on the fly optimizations and code swapping going on -- especially when the application starts up.

If you still need to be convinced that the `shuffle(...)` isn't a problem then put a for loop around your shuffle to see if it significantly increases the runtime of your application.

> Question 2. What is the Random rnd = r; in the above method supposed to do? Doesn't it just copy the reference? Why not use `Random rnd = new Random()` instead (which seems to solve my problems)?

Well first off, there is a `Collections.shuffle(List, Random)` method that allows you to set use your own local random.

As to the academic question about why does the method both have a local field `rnd` as well as the `static` field `r`, I suppose that this is trying to make sure that the shuffle method uses the `rnd` that was instantiated in the method and not one that might have been created by another thread since there is a race condition when 2 threads are storing to `r` and then using it.  If it isn't that then I'm not sure why the code was written that way.